# Django Admin Sortable 2 - Inline Tabular - not save order and display hidden field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sorting, django-admin

I was using Python 3.9, Django 3.2.8, and Django-admin-sortable2 1.0.3. I was facing issue that my custom order field (I named it "sort_order") was visible in inline tabular forms but it should have been hidden as per Django-admin-sortable2 implementation. And although I was able to drag-and-drop items, but upon saving the parent object, the sort order wasn't getting saved.

My admin classes were as follows:

```py
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet
from adminsortable2.admin import CustomInlineFormSet, SortableInlineAdminMixin

class ABCInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    ...
    pass

class ABCAdminInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    formset = ABCInlineFormSet
    model = models.MyModel
    fields = ["your_field"]
    ...
```

What worked for me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added some code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the hint for this problem in a little unrelated issue here: https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2/issues/106

I had specified a "formset" in my TabularInline admin class. So, I just tried inheriting my inline formset class with "CustomInlineFormSet" class of django-admin-sortable2. Which solved the problem for me.

```
from adminsortable2.admin import CustomInlineFormSet, SortableInlineAdminMixin

class ABCInlineFormSet(CustomInlineFormSet, BaseInlineFormSet):
    ...
    pass


class ABCAdminInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    formset = ABCInlineFormSet
    model = models.MyModel
    fields = ["your_field"]
    ...
```